# How to pass two strings as parameters to a perl script?

Tags: perl

I have written a perl script which extracts the contents of an excel sheet. The script prints out the contents of the excel sheet on the command line.
What I am stuck with?
I want a data mining kind of stuff with perl.
My excel sheet is like this...

```
  SUNY MARK 40%

  MIT  JOHN 60%

  UIUC LIU  77%
```

Suppose if I give 
myscript.pl `'SUNY' 'MARK'`
It should extract 40% and should print it out on the command line.

I am using `Spreedsheet::Parseexcel` so far.
But I am absolutely clueless on how to implement this feature.
Is using `ARGV[]` a good approach?
Help me out guys? Any idea is greatly appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you mean `@ARGV`.

Comment: I think you should go and learn a little more Perl instead of asking questions here.

Answer (score 1):

```
myscript.pl 'SUNY' 'MARK'
```

would store SUNY inside $ARGV[0] and MARK inside $ARGV[1]. You would then iterate over the rows, checking cell 0 and 1 to see if they match $ARGV[0] and $ARGV[1] and if so, return cell 2.

Comment: thanks for the quick response ... But this has to be dynamic right..as in I would not be searching for only SUNY and MARK but many matches like MIT JOHN,UIUC LIU,SAM HARVARD ( SAY ) , so I have to make many if conditions for the entire spreadsheet to be covered right ??

Comment: No. As I said: iterate through the excel sheet's rows and match cell A and B to $ARGV[0] and $ARGV[1], and if it does then print cell C.